# eMail address from SharedPreference for messageIntent

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I would like to send an email with the email addresses from the SharedPreferences.
The user should type the email address in the SharedPreferences and the message intent should use this address.

In moment I use this code to send an email with attachement and an fix address.
Please can someone show me the new code?

```
private final void mailNote() {
    Intent messageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    String aEmailList[] = { "Mailadresse@gmx.de" };
    messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList); 
    messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "eMail from APP");//eMail Text 
    messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Info"); //Betreff 
    // get the data from the cursor using the column index indicatormessage
    Intent.setType("plain/text"); 
    messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/CEDApp/CEDApp_export.txt"));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(messageIntent, "Email:")); 
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(messageIntent, "choose an option:");//Überschrift 
    // Send the note 
    startActivity(chooser); 
}
```

Thank you and regards from Germany,
Katsche

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences settings = null;
settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
eMailAdress = settings.getString("eMailAdress", ""); // Replace eMailAdress with your Pref name
```

Answer (score 0):

ich bin Android-Anfänger und habe das jetzt so umgestellt jedoch funktioniert das nicht, sprich es wird keine eMailadresse aus der SharedPreferences mit übergeben.

```
private final void mailNote() { 
Intent messageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
messageIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); 

SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()); 
eMailAdress = settings.getString("emailkey", ""); 
messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, eMailAdress); 

messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "eMail from CED-APP");//eMail Text 
messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "CED-Info"); //BetreffmessageIntent.setType("plain/text"); 
messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/CEDApp/CEDApp_export.txt"));startActivity(Intent.createChooser(messageIntent, "Email:")); 
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(messageIntent, "choose an option:");//Überschrift 
// Send the note 
startActivity(chooser); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, before your retrieve data from SharedPreferences, you also need to put it there :

```
settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
settings.edit().putString("emailKey", "my@email.com").commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to update my code like this:

```
private final void mailNote() {
Intent messageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
messageIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
settings.edit().putString("emailkey", "my@email.com").commit();

messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, eMailAdress); //<== ERROR

messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "eMail from CED-APP");//eMail Text
messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "CED-Info"); //Betreff
messageIntent.setType("plain/text");
messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/CEDApp/CEDApp_export.txt"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(messageIntent, "Email:"));
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(messageIntent, "choose an option:");//Überschrift
// Send the note
startActivity(chooser);
}
```

I think the line with the comment: ERROR is the problem or?